# How to apply .italic() to .largeTitle Font?

Tags: swiftui

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            ForEach(Font.TextStyle.allCases, id: \.self) { style in
                Text(self.describe(style: style)).font(.system(style)).italic()
            }
        }
    }
    func describe(style: Font.TextStyle) -> String {
        var s: String = ""
        print(style, terminator: "", to: &s)
        return s
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```

produce

[image]

is it a bug or I missed something?

Comment: i could reproduce that. looks like an error to me. you should file a bug report/radar.

Answer (score 2):

Final answer from Apple

> Resolution:Investigation complete - Works as currently designed

Have a lot of fun with Apple ...

Comment: Still a problem for me for UIFont in iOS 15.4.