# How to work with Font Modifiers? uppercased and font size in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swift5

I'm trying to create some default fonts for my app using modifiers. If there's an easier way, I'd love to know. Currently, I have

```
struct PrimaryLabel: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .font(Font.body.smallCaps())
            .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .light, design: .serif)) // this is not working. Only the first one will '.font' will work

    }
}
```

usability:

```
Text("Hello World").modifier(PrimaryLabel())
```

Is there a way to change the font type (ie like using AmericanTypewriter-Light font), make it all capitalized, and use a style like `weight: .light, design: .serif`, bold etc? I don't want to define every single Text. The second `.font` modifier in the struct is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first modifier is only visible, which is logical, try to apply few ,background or .foregroundColor .... it works the same way.

try

```
VStack {
    Text("ALFA").font(.largeTitle)
    Text("Beta").foregroundColor(Color.red)
}
.font(.system(size: 150))
.foregroundColor(Color.blue)
```

[image]

You can create Font with different initializers

```
init(CTFont)
```

Gets a font from a platform font instance.

```
static func system(Font.TextStyle, design: Font.Design) -> Font
```

Gets a system font with the given style and design.

```
static func system(size: CGFloat, weight: Font.Weight, design: Font.Design) -> Font
```

Specifies a system font to use, along with the style, weight, and any design parameters you want applied to the text.

```
static func custom(String, size: CGFloat) -> Font
```

Gets a custom font with the given name and size.

And you can further style your Text

Styling a Text View

```
func bold() -> Text
```

Applies a bold font weight to the text.

```
func italic() -> Text
```

Applies italics to the text.

```
func fontWeight(Font.Weight?) -> Text
```

Sets the font weight of the text.

```
func baselineOffset(CGFloat) -> Text
```

Sets the baseline offset for the text.

```
func tracking(CGFloat) -> Text
```

Sets the tracking for the text.

```
func kerning(CGFloat) -> Text
```

Sets the spacing, or kerning, between two characters.

```
func underline(Bool, color: Color?) -> Text
```

Applies an underline to the text.

```
func strikethrough(Bool, color: Color?) -> Text
```

Applies a strikethrough to the text.

WARNING!! 
 Not every combination is supported! 
see [How to apply .italic() to .largeTitle Font?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59640260/how-to-apply-italic-to-largetitle-font)

Answer (score 2):

```
extension View {
    func primaryLabelStyle(_ weight: Font.Weight) -> some View {
        return self.modifier(PrimaryLabel(weight: weight))
    }
}

struct PrimaryLabel: ViewModifier {
    let weight: Font.Weight
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .font(Font.body.smallCaps())
            .font(.system(size: 20, weight: weight, design: .serif)) // this is not working. Only the first one will '.font' will work

    }
}

Text("Hello World").primaryLabelStyle(.light)
```